Can we express the Law of the Unconscious Statistician using the CDF instead of the PDF?
I have only seen LOTUS given either in terms of the density
$$\mathbb{E}[g(X)] = \int g(x) f(x) dx$$
or in terms of the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral
$$\mathbb{E}[g(X)] = \int g(x) dF_X(x).$$
I have also seen this post showing how moments can be computed using the CDF and not the PDF:

Similar to computing these moments, is there a way to write the LOTUS using the CDF and not the PDF?

Hm. Isn't LOTUS expressed in terms of $\mathrm F_X$ in your second expression "a way to write the LOTUS using the CDF and not the PDF"?

The Lebesgue-Stieltjes form of LOTUS appears to me to already do this.  Is there some aspect of this form that is not to your liking?

Computing the area under a curve, in terms of horizontal strips or vertical strips  and the swap between them, I believe this has a name (something with Euler or another big famous name).

@SextusEmpiricus, you might be talking about Cavalieri's Principle.

Result $1.$ Let $(\Omega,\boldsymbol{\mathfrak A},\mu)$ be a $\sigma$–finite measure space and let $f$ be a non-negative real-valued $\boldsymbol{\mathfrak A}$–measurable function on $\Omega.$ Let $\nu$ be a $\sigma$–finite measure on the measurable space $([0,\infty),\boldsymbol{\mathfrak B}_{[0,\infty)}).$ Define a function $\varphi(\cdot)$ on $[0,\infty)$ as $t\mapsto \nu([0,t]).$ Then $$\int_\Omega \varphi(f(\omega))~\mu(\mathrm d\omega)=\int_{[0,\infty) }\mu\{\omega\in\Omega\mid f(\omega)\geq t\}~\nu(\mathrm dt).\tag 1\label 1$$
Note $\varphi(\cdot) $ is an increasing function owing to its definition and hence a real-valued measurable function on $([0, \infty), \boldsymbol{\mathfrak B}_{[0,\infty)}).$
Consider the product space $(\Omega\times [0, \infty), \sigma(\boldsymbol{\mathfrak A}\times\boldsymbol{\mathfrak B}_{[0, \infty) }), \mu\times \nu) $ and let $E:=\{(\omega,t)\in\Omega\times [0,\infty)\mid f(\omega)\geq t\}.$ Therefore $$\begin{align}(\mu\times \nu)(E)&=\int_{[0,\infty)}\mu(E(\cdot,t))~\nu(\mathrm dt) \\&=\int_{[0,\infty)}\mu\{\omega\in\Omega\mid f(\omega)\geq t\}~\nu(\mathrm dt) \end{align};$$
again
$$\begin{align}(\mu\times \nu)(E)&=\int_\Omega \nu(E(\omega,\cdot))~\mu(\mathrm d\omega)\\&\int_X\nu\{t\in[0,\infty) \mid f(\omega)\geq t\}~\mu(\mathrm d\omega) \\&=\int_\Omega \nu([0,f(\omega)])~\mu(\mathrm d\omega) \\&=\int_\Omega \varphi(f(\omega))~\mu(\mathrm d\omega).\end{align}$$
$\blacksquare$
Result $2.$ Let $(\Omega,\boldsymbol{\mathfrak A},\mu)$ be a $\sigma$–finite measure space and let $f$ be a non-negative real-valued $\boldsymbol{\mathfrak A}$–measurable function on $\Omega.$ Consider a non-negative real-valued increasing and absolutely continuous function on $[0,\infty),~\varphi(\cdot)$ such that $\varphi(0)=0.$ Then $$\int_\Omega \varphi(f(\omega))\mu(\mathrm d\omega) =\int_{[0,\infty)}\mu\{\omega\in\Omega\mid f(\omega)\geq t\}\varphi^\prime(t)~\lambda(\mathrm dt).\tag 2\label 2$$
Extend $\varphi(\cdot) $ by setting $\varphi(t) =0~~\forall t\in(-\infty, 0).$ Therefore $\varphi(\cdot) $ is a real-valued measurable function increasing and absolutely continuous on $\mathbb R. $ Consider the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure on $(\mathbb R, \boldsymbol{\mathfrak B}_{\mathbb R}) $ associated with $\varphi$ on $\mathbb R. $ This implies $\nu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ with RN derivative $\frac{\mathrm d\nu}{\mathrm d\lambda} =\varphi^\prime$ a.e. on $(\mathbb R, \boldsymbol{\mathfrak B}_{\mathbb R}). $ Note that $\nu([0, t]) =\varphi(t) -\varphi(0) =\varphi(t). $ Restrict $\nu$ on $([0,\infty),\boldsymbol{\mathfrak B}_{[0,\infty)});~\varphi(\cdot),\nu$ satisfy the conditions of Result $1.$ So,
\begin{align}\int_\Omega \varphi(f(\omega))~\mu(\mathrm d\omega)&=\int_{[0,\infty)} \mu\{\omega\in\Omega \mid f(\omega)\geq t\}~\nu(\mathrm dt) \\&=\int_{[0,\infty)}\mu\{\omega\in\Omega\mid f(\omega)\geq t\}\left(\frac{\mathrm d\nu}{\mathrm d\lambda}\right)(t)~\lambda(\mathrm dt) \\&=\int_{[0,\infty)}\mu\{\omega\in\Omega\mid f(\omega)\geq t\}\varphi^\prime(t)~\lambda(\mathrm dt).\end{align}
$\blacksquare$
Corollary $1.$ For $p\geq 1,$ $$\int_\Omega (f(\omega))^p\mu(\mathrm d\omega) =p\int_{[0,\infty)}t^{p-1}\mu\{\omega\in\Omega\mid f(\omega)\geq t\}~\lambda(\mathrm dt).\tag 3\label 3$$
Take $\varphi$ as $t\mapsto t^p, ~t\in[0, \infty) ;$ it satisfies the conditions of Result $2.$ and hence from $\eqref 2,~\eqref 3$ follows.
$\blacksquare$
In a probability space, for a non-negative random variable $X, $ by $\eqref 3,$ one can write
$${\mathbf E}[X^p]=p\int_{[0,\infty)} x^{p-1}(1-\mathrm F_X(x)) ~\mathrm dx. $$
--
Reference:
$\rm[I]$ Real Analysis: Theory of Measure and Integration, J. Yeh, World Scientific, $2014, $ sec. $5.23.\mathrm V. $

You can do this when $g(x)$ is a monotonous function.
$$E[g(X)] = g(0) + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g'(x) H(x) dx$$
Where
$$H(x) = \begin{cases} 
-F_X(x) & \quad \text{if $x  \leq 0$}\\
1-F_X(x) & \quad \text{if $x  > 0$}
\end{cases}$$
